# char array to int in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I am unable to get the part of the string stored in form of char array.

```
char code1 [12]={0};
char c;
string compressed_file;
```

I am taking the input from a text file, till a ',' occurs in it.

```
cout<<"Input compressed_file name"<<endl;
cin>>compressed_file;
string extracted_file;
cout<<"Input extracted_file name"<<endl;
cin>>extracted_file;

ifstream input;
input.open(compressed_file.c_str());
ofstream decompresscode;
decompresscode.open(extracted_file.c_str());

input>>c;
while(c != ',')
{
    int i=0;
    code1[i]=c;
    cout<<code1[i];
    i++;
    input>>c;
}
int old=atoi(code1);
cout<<old;
```

After printing the value of code1 here, I am only getting the first letter of the array. My `code1` is **66**, it is printing only **6**.

Comment: Consider using an `std::vector<char>` instead of your array. This enables longer input and you would not need the variable `i`, select the `back()` element instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are always saving in the position `0`:

```
int i=0; // this need to be out of while loop
code1[i]=c;
cout<<code1[i];
```

You need also to add a check for read at max 12 char (to not overflow `code1`). The code could be something like.

```
input >> c;
int i = 0;
while (c != ',' && i < sizeof(code1)) {
    code1[i] = c;
    cout << code1[i];
    i++;
    input >> c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `int i = 0` *outside the loop*. As it is, you are resetting it to `0` each time.

```
input>>c;
int i=0; //move to here
while(c != ',')
{        
    code1[i]=c;
    cout<<code1[i];
    i++;
    input>>c;
}
```